# Django App Engine can't find antlr3 module

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm trying to set up a Django app to run on GAE, and am using the on_production_server test to choose between dev vs. production settings in settings.py.

However, when I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    import settings
  File "/home/guillaume/myproject/settings.py", line 10, in <module>
    from djangoappengine.utils import on_production_server, have_appserver
  File "/home/guillaume/myproject/djangoappengine/utils.py", line 18, in <module>
    'Error was: %s' % e)
Exception: Could not get appid. Is your app.yaml file missing? 
Error was: No module named antlr3
```

I tried adding the following to settings.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/')
```

And this line to the very end of .profile:

```
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/google_appengine/"
```

But neither gets rid of the error.  I'm really new to working with paths so I'm kind of fumbling around blindly here.  Can anyone help?

Comment: django-appengine-patch is *massively* deprecated, it hasn't been updated for years. What made you choose to use it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I'm working on a bunch of Django learning projects, so I just need a way to deploy them online for free.  If you know of a better (and equally free) way of getting Django sites hosted, I'd LOVE to know about it...having to deal with GAE's NoSQL limitations has been a pain, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Python2.5v or 2.7v?
And what about GAE SDK version?

Did you [try](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/issues/detail?id=118) this?

Comment: Python 2.7.3; GAE SDK 1.6.6.  I looked at the link in your post but I can't find a folder titled "appengine_django" anywhere on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this question while having the same problem. Solved it by installing antlr 3.1.1 python runtime from [Here](http://www.antlr3.org/download/Python/).