# Error importing simplejson and antlr3 to djangoappengine project

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, djangoappengine

I'm building a project that uses django-app-engine, but get some import errors when running the project with the GAE launcher.

My first error is importing simplejson, same as: [Error importing simplejson after upgrading to appengine dev server 1.7.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756022/error-importing-simplejson-after-upgrading-to-appengine-dev-server-1-7-6)

I've resolved that issue by modifying old_dev_appserver.py in the GAE bundle to import 'json' instead of 'simplejson' (I hope it's ok that I modified the GAE bundle..)

After the change, I receive a new error:

```
 File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/cron/groc.py", line 31, in <module>
    import antlr3
ImportError: No module named antlr3
```

In the link above, @trope actually commented on having the same issue, but I thought a new question would be better than adding comments to the original issue (which is resolved by changing simplejson to json)

As suggested here: [Django App Engine can't find antlr3 module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806237/django-app-engine-cant-find-antlr3-module), I've tried to add

```
os.path.join(SDK_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3')
```

And also tried to install the antlr3 runtime.

I feel this issue is different to the one above because it's a direct result of the simplejson workaround, but perhaps it is the same.

Python 2.7.2, GAELauncher 1.9.4

Any suggestions?

edit: I've also now tried the exact same setup/codebase on my PC with the latest version of Launcher, and I get the exact same two errors: first simplejson, then antlr3. Maybe that means it's an issue with the codebase/djangoappengine install?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this should be solved.  Make sure you have updated all the django nonrel projects (dbindexer, django, djangoappengine, djangotoolbox, and whatever else you use).  Also, run `gcloud components update` from the command line.

In addition to adding `os.path.join(SDK_PATH, 'lib', 'antlr3')`, did you also actually download and install it?  From the command line, run `whereis antlr3`.

Comment: I must be doing something very wrong. I've tried to update all my components. I've ran the gcloud update (everything is up to date)

When I install the antlr3 runtime, it says Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.1-py2.7.egg

however, when I run antlr3 in terminal or which antlr3, I get nothing..